# How to get Xresources background color

Tags: x11, xterm, x-resources

I tried with `xrdb -query -all`. But it does not give the Xterm default background color code. My background color is cornflower blue. But I could not see that in list. Can any one let me know how to know that?

Answer (score 1):

[`appres XTerm xterm`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/appres.1.xhtml) shows all the resources read by Xterm when invoked under the name `xterm`. This includes both user customizations uploaded to the X server (visible with `xrdb -query`) and default files read on the client side by the application.

The first argument is the class name (conventionally starting with an uppercase letter; you can change it by running `xterm -class OtherName`). The second argument (optional) is the instance name (conventionally starting with a lowercase letter; you can change it by renaming the executable or passing the `-name` option).

Answer (score 0):

X11 applications like `xterm` get their resources like the background colour from many places.
`xrdb` only lists resources held by the X11 server.

If you look in the man page for `xterm` you will find in the `FILES` section the names of files that are also read for resources. On my system they are

```
   /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
   /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color
   ~/.Xdefaults
```

If you want the names of the colours like `CornflowerBlue`, they are held in a text file. On my system they are in `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.